# SSRS: Passing/Setting parameter to Dataset using Expression

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ms-reports

I am using **Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0**. I have created a **Stored Procedure** (*stored_procedure1*) in the database which has a **Parameter** (*parameter1*). Here, *stored_procedure1* returns *result1*.

Then, I used *stored_procedure1* to create a **Dataset** (*dataset1*) in the **Microsoft SQL Report Builder 3.0**. Next, I created a **Table** (*table1*) in **Microsoft SQL Report Builder 3.0** with 2 rows and 2 columns (total 4 cells).

I would like to fill each element of *table1* with *result1* from dataset1. Hence, I set expression of each cell of *table1* as follows:

***=Sum(Fields!result1.Value, "dataset1")***

When I run this report, it works perfectly and asks me to enter *parameter1*. However, I want to use single **Dataset** (*dataset1*) with different values of *parameter1* for each cell of the table. Hence, I want to pass/set *parameter1* with unique *parameter_value* for each expression of table cells. Say I want to set *parameter1 = parameter_value1* for first cell.

For example, if I need to set *parameter_value = 5*, I did something like

***=Sum(Fields!result1.Value, "dataset1"), Parameters!parameter1.Value = 5***

I also tried following:

***=Sum(Fields!result1.Value, "dataset1") & Parameters!parameter1.Value = 5***.

It doesn't work.

In summary, I coudln't pass or set parameter value together with an expression.
Can we set/parameter value.

I would like to thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone got stuck with this problem, I found a way around for this. T

here is no way one can pass parameter within expression.

You will need to create a subreport to do this. You can pass parameter to subreport.

Its little time consuming. However, it seems there is no other way around.